# pandas largest value per group with multi columns / why does it only work when flattening?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

For a pandas dataframe of:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 1], 'anomaly_score':[5, 10, 8, 100], 'match_level_0':[np.nan, 1, 1, 1], 'match_level_1':[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1], 'match_level_2':[np.nan, 1, 1, 1]
})
display(df)
df = df.groupby(['id', 'match_level_0']).agg(['mean', 'sum'])
```

I want to calculate the largest rows per group.

```
df.columns = ['__'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
df.groupby(['id'])['anomaly_score__mean'].nlargest(2)
```

Works but requires to flatten the multiindex for the columns.

Instead I want to directly use,

```
df.groupby(['id'])[('anomaly_score', 'mean')].nlargest(2)
```

But this fails with the key not being found.
Interestingly, it works just fine when not grouping:

```
df[('anomaly_score', 'mean')].nlargest(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me working grouping by `Series` with first level of `MultiIndex`, but it seems bug why not working like in your solution:

```
print (df[('anomaly_score', 'mean')].groupby(level=0).nlargest(2))
id  match_level_0
1   1.0              55
2   1.0               8
Name: (anomaly_score, mean), dtype: int64

print (df[('anomaly_score', 'mean')].groupby(level='id').nlargest(2))
```